# Glyph Metrics in Objective-C with Core Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, fonts, core-text

I have a `UniChar` and I am using `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph` to draw the paths.  But I need to know all [of the information](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Art/glyphterms_2x.png) about the glyph, particularly left-side-bearing and baseline.  My requirements are that I need it to work on both MacOS and iOS and to be done in Objective-C (not Swift).  Is this possible?  I have been searching and am having trouble finding a clear example of how to do this.